# make accordion in jquery will retain open on navigate

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am working on accordion in jquery and on click of li it will navigate and accordion will also close . i want accordion retain open on navigate.how i will do this please help me

Comment: Do you a link? Can you create a demo?

Comment: what do you mean by it will navigate?

Comment: Try event.preventDefault() on click?

Comment: No need of using accordion for what you want, this is not for what accordions have been designed

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to create a cookie using javascript that stores the open/close state of the accordion. On load of the page you are navigating to, check the value of that cookie and open the accordion as needed.

Maybe not the best way, but it should work.